# How to changing the row and column index within the nested for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to figure out the shortest distance traveling the city. 
I already have a start point, the city '0', then we will visit every single city without revisiting the previous city. In this case, we do not need to come back to city 0.

Let's suppose we have 4 cities then we will have a matrix with the distance.
What I am trying to do is that I will iterate through every possible route and get the cost for each route.

So all the possible route with city number 4 is

```
city[0][1] + city[1][2] + city[2][3] 
city[0][1] + city[1][3] + city[3][2] 

city[0][2] + city[2][1] + city[1][3] 
city[0][2] + city[2][3] + city[3][1] 

city[0][3] + city[3][1] + city[1][2] 
city[0][3] + city[3][2] + city[2][1]
```

My question is how can I make the nested for-loop for those equations? 
I could see that there is a pattern that the "column index" should go to the next "row index" and so on.

Comment: You don't want to iterate over the distance table, that won't give you sums. You want to iterate over *routes*, and those are *permutations* of your set of cities. Google "permutations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the permutations of all cities where the first city is fixed. If the number of cities if fixed, you can write that meny nested `for` loops, but that gets cumbersome quickly.

Instead, permute the array recursively:

- Create an array `path` of the order of visting the cities; start with {0, ..., *N* − 1}.
- Pick a starting index. If you want all possible starting pints, pick 0. Here, the first city is fixed, so start at index 1, because `path[1]` is the first entry that should change.
- Call the permutation function:

  - Now if there are still cities to permute, swap each of them to the next position in turn, call the permutation function with the next index, then swap the city back. As you recurse, keep track of the current distance.
  - If there aren't any more cities, you have reached the end of the list. Print the path and the distance or whatever you want to do and don't do anything else.

Here's how that might look in code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
    N = 4           // number of cities
};

const int city[N][N] = {
    {0, 2, 5, 5},
    {2, 0, 3, 4},
    {5, 3, 0, 6},
    {5, 4, 6, 0},
};

/*
 *      Swap array elements at indices i and j
 */
void swap(int a[], int i, int j)
{
    if (i != j) {
        int swap = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = swap;
    }
}

/*
 *      Permute the subarray of length n, starting at index i
 */
void perm(int path[], int i, int n, int weight)
{
    int j;

    if (i == n) {                                   // path is exhausted:
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {                   // print path and distance
            printf("%c ", 'A' + path[j]);
        }

        printf("-> %d\n", weight);
    } else {                                        // more cities to visit:
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {                   // pick each of them as ...
            int w = 0;                              // ... destination

            if (i > 0) {                            // determine distance ...
                w = city[path[i - 1]][path[j]];     // ... from prev. city,
            }                                       // ... if any

            swap(path, i, j);                       // swap city in;
            perm(path, i + 1, n, weight + w);       // recurse;
            swap(path, i, j);                       // swap city back
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int path[N];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) path[i] = i;            // initial path

    perm(path, 1, N, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a detail, you do not need to check  `if (i > 0) {` in _perm_, it starts with 1 and is always incremented  in the recursive calls. UV of course ^^

Comment: @bruno: Thanks, but I wanted to make the procedure more general and I also mention that you could start at index 0 in the text somewhere, so I wanted to rule out that case.